# Insert multiple checkboxlist values to sql db asp.net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkboxlist

I am trying to insert multiple CheckBoxList values that are INT to a SQL DB using ASP.NET C#. I have set a breakpoint in my code and the loop works but once it picks up the first selected value, it stays with that value and causes a Primary Key Constraint. In the end, it just inserts one value. After a couple days of research, all my findings show how to insert multiple strings to a SQL DB but none for INT. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cbAvailableEntities.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertProjectEntity", con);

        using(con)
        {
            con.Open();
            using(cmd)
            {
                 if (cbAvailableEntities.Items[i].Selected)
                 {
                     //This code gets the Project ID that is to be associated with the new info
                     DALSectionAccessData LastProjectID = new DALSectionAccessData(connString);
                     //This puts the Project ID needed into the variable _pID
                     int _pID = LastProjectID.GetLastLogReportID();
                     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                     nr.Entities = cbAvailableEntities.SelectedValue;
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", _pID);
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpID", nr.Entities);
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  }
            }
        }
}
```

This is what the error says

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProjectEntity'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProjectEntity'. The statement
>   has been terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of
>   PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ProjectEntity'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.ProjectEntity'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: Is the constraint being violated on the CorpID column? `nr.Entities = cbAvailableEntities.SelectedValue;` should probably be `nr.Entities = cb.AvailableEntities.Items[i].SelectedValue;` otherwise it looks like the CorpID will always be the same. If this isn't the case, what does your code in GetLastLogReportID look like?

Comment: The constraint is being caused by CorpID. CorpID is supposed to be the one changing each time it goes through the loop since the value of the checkboxlist (cbAvailableEntities) is the one being inputted. I am editing my post to show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, you are checking in the if() statement to see if `Item[i]` is selected, but if it is you are not doing anything with `Item[i]` to differentiate one iteration from the next.   Therefore you are running the same exact code for every selected item in the checkboxlist, rather than doing something different for each.

Try changing this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpID", nr.Entities);
```

to something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorpID", cbAvailableEntities.Items[i].Value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it although I put 
nr.Entities = cbAvailableEntities.Items[i].Value; 
instead. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working on the Update portion of the program. It is basically the same code except everytime it updates the row, it removes the previously inputted value.

Comment: Sounds like you are updating the same row over and over then, instead of setting the CorpID differently in each iteration of the loop.   But this is happening in a part of the code you haven't posted, so I can only guess.

Comment: I will post a new question since this question was for Inserting a new row and you have answered it. Thank you very much for your help.